# need a simple query in t-sql

Tags: t-sql

I have a query that I have simplified for our purpose. How do you achieve this result ?

```
ID OrigId
----------
1   1
2   1
3   3
4   4
5   4
6   6

Result

ID OrigId
----------
1   1
2   1
4   4
5   4
```

Comment: What are you trying to exclude?  Are you filtering out on ID or OrigID?

Comment: Am I the only one not following this?  Are you trying to filter out anything that hasn't changed from its original?  In which case, why does 4,4 get returned but not 6,6?

Comment: @MikeChristensen - The explanation from the OP is non existent but it seems to be rows where the `OrigId` appears more than once that should be returned.

Comment: Oh, I see it now - Yeah it's like a fun "find the pattern" puzzle!

Comment: Voted down for the ultimate vagueness of doom.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a HAVING statement

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.Table
WHERE OrigID IN
(
SELECT OrigID
FROM dbo.Table
GROUP BY OrigID
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
)
```

Answer (score 4):

To bring back all rows where the corresponding `OrigId` appears more than once in the table you can use

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
SELECT *,
       COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY OrigId) AS C
FROM YourTable
)
SELECT ID,
       OrigId
FROM CTE
WHERE C >1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select *
from selecttest
where origid in
(
    select origid
    from selecttest
    group by origid
    having COUNT(*) > 1
)
```

Comment: How is this different from @msmucker0527's answer posted 7 minutes before?

Comment: @MartinSmith it is not.  I was writing the query before I saw his post.  I can delete if you like.

Comment: Yours has better tabbing in the subquery

Comment: @msmucker0527 Hahahaha that's the best comment I've seen all week.  Ah, the beauty of tab sugar.